# How to write `$("user")` in kotlin with flink

Tags: kotlin, apache-flink

from flink 1.14, it suggest using $() for retrieving elements like below:

```
Table table = tableEnv.fromDataStream(ds, $("user"), $("product"), $("amount"));
```

so is there a way to convert it to kotlin, for it causing compiler error in kotlin:

```
var table = tableEnv.fromDataStream(ds, $("user"), $("product"), $("amount"));
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not familiar with Apache Flink, but you're not allowed to use the dollar sign on it's own.

For function names with special characters, e.g. whitespace, you have to put the function name into backticks (`` ` ``), e.g.:

```kotlin
fun `white space`() = Unit
fun `$`() = Unit


fun main() {
    `white space`()
    `$`()
}
```

Thus, your code example above works on my machine with the following adjustments.

```kotlin
import org.apache.flink.table.api.Expressions.*

...

val table = tableEnv.fromDataStream(ds, `$`("user"), `$`("product"), `$`("amount"))
```

Comment: yes it does!!, it works, can't believe kotlin have such syntactic sugar

Comment: It's needed in Kotlin for Java compatibility. For example, Java's standard input stream is called `System.in` — but that wouldn't be valid in Kotlin, where `in` is a keyword. So Kotlin needs a mechanism such as backquoting to allow you to access all the valid Java identifiers. Luckily, it also allows a wide range of other identifiers too!

Answer (score 2):

This problem will be fixed in one of the next Flink releases:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-26278